# Drop nan rows in pandas that are not in the middle

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which are indexed  by time,

For example:

```
Time                       Value
2010-01-01                 nan
2010-01-02                 nan
2010-01-03                 3
2010-01-04                 4
2010-01-05                 5
2010-01-06                 3
2010-01-07                 nan
2010-01-08                 nan
2010-01-09                 3
2010-01-10                 3
2010-01-11                 4
2010-01-12                 5
2010-01-13                 3
2010-01-14                 nan
2010-01-15                 nan
```

In this example, I would like to drop the first two and last two rows. But not the rows with nan in the middle. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What defines “in the middle”? Would a `NaN` in `2010-01-04` be deleted? Are you just trying to remove all continuous `NaN` rows that are at the start or end?

Comment: Yes. A NAN on 2010-01-04 should not be deleted

Answer (score 5):

You can use index of first valid value and last valid value to filter the dataframe:

```
df.loc[df.Value.first_valid_index(): df.Value.last_valid_index()]
```

Result:

```
            Value
Time             
2010-01-03    3.0
2010-01-04    4.0
2010-01-05    5.0
2010-01-06    3.0
2010-01-07    NaN
2010-01-08    NaN
2010-01-09    3.0
2010-01-10    3.0
2010-01-11    4.0
2010-01-12    5.0
2010-01-13    3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing `data` is your dataframe:

```
a, b = data.dropna().index[[0, -1]]
```

You could also consider selecting a specific column, e.g. using `data['Value']` instead of `data`.

This way you get the starting and ending indices *not containing NaN*. Then you just have to get that slice (being careful to include that last row):

```
data[a:b+1]
```

Result:

```
Time                       Value
2010-01-03                 3
2010-01-04                 4
2010-01-05                 5
2010-01-06                 3
2010-01-07                 nan
2010-01-08                 nan
2010-01-09                 3
2010-01-10                 3
2010-01-11                 4
2010-01-12                 5
2010-01-13                 3
```

Single-row solution following @unutbu's tip to use `loc`:

```
data.loc[slice(*data.dropna().index[[0, -1]])]
```

Comment: To avoid the +1 in `data[a:b+1]`, you could also use `data.loc[a,b]` since `loc` includes both endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bfill` and `ffill`

```
df[df.Value.ffill().notnull()&df.Value.bfill().notnull()]
Out[464]: 
          Time  Value
2   2010-01-03    3.0
3   2010-01-04    4.0
4   2010-01-05    5.0
5   2010-01-06    3.0
6   2010-01-07    NaN
7   2010-01-08    NaN
8   2010-01-09    3.0
9   2010-01-10    3.0
10  2010-01-11    4.0
11  2010-01-12    5.0
12  2010-01-13    3.0
```